# Typescript not compiling enums to numbers

Tags: typescript, enums, tsc

I'm trying to use typescript to essentially write json data with a schema, so I need the Typescript compiler to compile enums into numbers in the js outputs but I can't get this to work.

I've tried a good few things already, [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11202) post is similar to the issue I'm having but I'm not using awesome-typescript-loader, I've also tried everything [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700306/const-enum-in-typescript-tsc-js-vs-typescript-js) stack overflow post but no joy. My ts-config is below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": false,
    "sourceMap": false
},
    "include": [
      "src/**/*"
    ]
  }
```

I'm simply calling `tsc` on the command line in the root directory, it compiles everything but enums are compiled as `MyEnum_1.MyEnum.FirstValue`.
Other things I've tried;

- Changing the module to various different options
- Changing the target to various different options
- Adding different options and playing around with different lib values.

I'm running tsc -v 3.6.4 and have run out of ideas, has anyone had a similar issue?

EDIT: Below is an example of the type of enum I'm importing

```
export enum MyEnum {
    Undefined,
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue,
    ThirdValue
}
```

EDIT: My an example of a typescript file would be...

```
import { MyEnum } from "../../src/models/MyEnum";
import { ItemType } from "../../src/models/ItemType";

var item: ItemType = { 
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "value": MyEnum.FirstValue
}
```

I would expect this to compile to...

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var MyEnum_1 = require("../../src/models/MyEnum");
var ItemType_1 = require("../../src/models/ItemType");
var item = {
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "value": 1
};
```

Instead it compiles to;

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var MyEnum_1 = require("../../src/models/MyEnum");
var ItemType_1 = require("../../src/models/ItemType");
var item = {
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "value": MyEnum_1.MyEnum.FirstValue
};
```

I pretty much don't care how it compiles as long as the enum compiles to a number.

Comment: Can you show the code that defines your `enum`s?

Comment: @VLAZ I've updated

Comment: How exactly should your output look like? Also how are you applying that enum?

Comment: @Marv I've updated with an example

Comment: So you want the compiled code to not have an enum that evaluates to a number, but you instead want it to compile to constant numbers? (`item.value` would actually be a numerical value if that is how the enum is defined, FYI)

Comment: Why is the resulting javascript from importance? If you want to turn a js object into JSON, use `JSON.stringify(item)`

Comment: @crashmstr correct, and yes item.value is a number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [const enums](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums):

```
export const enum MyEnum {
    Undefined,
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue,
    ThirdValue
}
var item = { 
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "value": MyEnum.FirstValue
}
```

compiles to

```
var MyEnum;
(function (MyEnum) {
// stuff
})(MyEnum || (MyEnum = {}));

var item = {
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "value": 1 /* FirstValue */
};
```

and if you want to skip the enum declaration altogether, make it [ambient](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#ambient-enums) as well:

```
export declare const enum MyEnum {
   ...
}
var item = { 
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "value": MyEnum.FirstValue
}
```

gives just

```
var item = {
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "value": 1 /* FirstValue */
};
```